# What's the correct jquery function to remove href surrounding text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a CSM platform and plugin to generate a navigation. The plugin is a little clunky and limited on controls so I'm trying to use jQuery to influence some basic style changes.

The problem seems simple enough to solve. I want to remove an unwanted A HREF="" surrounding the text in a specific list-item but my logic isn't working.

I'm using:

```
$( "li.dropdown-header" ).parent().removeAttr( "href");
```

To try and remove the anchor link attribute from the below

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-header"><a href="">Header Title</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any insight or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to remove the `anchor` element inside the `li` with class `dropdown-header`

```js
$("li.dropdown-header a").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="">Header Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! And thanks for pointing out typo @chipChocolate, was wondering why it was throwing console log error.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong selector for targeting anchor element. use correct selector:

```
$( "li.dropdown-header a").removeAttr( "href");
```

or for completely removing the anchor element and keeping text within it:

```
$( "li.dropdown-header a").contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: You have a typo ----------> `.content()` should be `.contents()`

Answer (score 1):

please check this.

```
$( ".dropdown-header" ).each(function(){
$(this).prev().find('a').removeAttr("href");
$(this).find('a').removeAttr("href");    
$(this).next().find('a').removeAttr("href");
```

$(this).next().next().find('a').removeAttr("href");
   });